# How change format date in postgresql

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I have a `PostgreSQL` query:

```
SELECT "message" FROM "mytable" 
WHERE "start_date" <= current_date AND "end_date" >= current_date
```

The `current_date` is the date of the system, for example today current system is: `29-08-2019`

the type of all the fields are `String`.
the format of the `current_date` is `"YYYY-DD-MM"`, and the format of the `start_date and end_date are "DD-MM-YYYY"`

How can I change the format of `current_date to "DD-MM-YYYY`" using postgresql or javascript ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Postgres

You can use any of the methods listed under "[Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)" section of the docs. For comparisons, either use `to_date()` or `to_timestamp()` functions.

### Javascript

There isn't a direct method on the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class but you use a snippet for this.

```
const datetime = new Date()
const date = datetime.toISOString().split('T')[0]
const formattedDate = date.split('-').reverse().join('-')
```

Comment: This is helpful but not quite right. The correct order of the split parts is `[parts[1], parts[2], parts[0]].join('-')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_char()` function for formatting date strings

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=881aa164c24b814060112663a3230200)

```
SELECT to_char(current_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

---

In your case, using it for comparison, it would be much better to format the strings into dates, so there should be a type `date` comparison instead of a type `text` comparison (using `to_date()` function).

One reason: The string comparison with dates formatted like that yours, would yield in errors:

```
01-02-2019 < 31-01-2019
```

because the text `31` is greater than the text `01`.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=739d31767ceb8dbfba3e8611ba12a67d)

```
WHERE current_date BETWEEN to_date(start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') and to_date(end_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```